# Is it possible to make a nested loop run asynchronously in python?

Tags: python, pandas, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I was trying to run a cosine similarity code to check if two strings are similar inside my list of strings to make the list containing unique strings only to remove sentences that are similar. I took one string and compared it with every other string in the list. The method I implemented is O(n^2) and will take a month minimum to finish for all my strings. I was thinking if I could run the nested loop tasks in parallel to reduce the time using asyncio.

So I tried something very similar to this but it doesn't work asynchronously. Kindly guide me a little bit. thank you.

```
async def dumb_add(i,j):
    print("adding",i,"+",j)
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(0,3))
    print(i,"+",j,"=",(i+j))

async def main():
    for i in range(0,2):
        for j in range(0,2):
            await dumb_add(i,j)
    print('main done')

asyncio.create_task(main())
```

Results:

```
adding 0 + 0
0 + 0 = 0
adding 0 + 1
0 + 1 = 1
adding 1 + 0
1 + 0 = 1
adding 1 + 1
1 + 1 = 2
main done
```

Comment: You should create tasks in your main function, and await those results. Then use `asyncio.run(main)` to run the main.

Comment: If your tasks are CPU intensive you might want to consider multiprocessing

Comment: What similarity code are you using? Have you tried [RapidFuzz](https://github.com/maxbachmann/RapidFuzz) or [tfidf-matcher](https://pypi.org/project/tfidf-matcher/)?

Comment: @jqurious i was using a cosine similarity function code that i copied without permission from s.o. i'll try out those two you linked, could be a better solution. thanks for those. tfidf-matcher looks more like what i was looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not running in parallel because the "await" keyword
is causing the co-routine to wait for each "dumb_add" call to finish, before moving on to the next one.
Therefore, the calls run sequentially rather than concurrently.

If you want to run your "dumb_add" function in parallel, you should use asyncio.gather().
In this way, you can create a list of routines that can be executed in parallel.

Something like this:

```
async def dumb_add(i,j):
    print("adding",i,"+",j)
    await asyncio.sleep(random.randint(0,3))
    print(i,"+",j,"=",(i+j))

async def main():
    tasks = []
    for i in range(0,2):
        for j in range(0,2):
            tasks.append(dumb_add(i,j))
    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)
    print('main done')

asyncio.run(main())
```